# Reusing a table, without a need for a PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a project that consists of two parts. The first part is nearly finished and I just started with the second part.

The table in question has a primary key (WorkerID) that is being used through the first part (a workerID is connected to a specific task that was completed by this employee). Now I want to reuse this table for the second part of the project. Sadly this second part has no need for a WorkerID but all of the other columns are needed.

What do you suggest for re-using the same table but skipping entering PK.

[image: Table with PK]

Comment: What is the difference between `Id` and `WorkerId` in your table`? Do you assign them both at the same time in your code?

Comment: ID is incremental and is auto added for each insert. WorkerID is added manually. Yes, both are assigned at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following modifications, It will help:

```
1. Make ID as Primary key , Remove WorkerID as PK.
2. add a new column(flag) which will indicate the record 
   will be used in Part1 or Part2.
3. In part1 use WorkerID with where condition using FLAG as Part1
4. For Part 2 WorkerID will be blank
```

This way you should be able to use the table for both the parts.